# can't have spring annotation in intellij

Tags: spring, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

i am new to intellij and all the annotation of spring are in red,i have download the spring data jpa when creating maven project and its still like this..
for example @entity (see photos)

[image]

[image]

Comment: only do maven reimport

Comment: user @Entity instead of lower case, and import javax.persistence.Entity;

Answer (score 0):

only do maven reimport because Spring hasn't loaded the libraries

Answer (score 0):

Use @Entity with a captial E rather than small e. You will also need to include the relevant java persistence dependency in your pom.xml. This can be found from www.mvnrepository.com

Include the import statement below in your class:

import javax.persistence.Entity;